# How to declare and fullfill three-dimentional array of arrays?

Tags: java

I need help completing one task from Java book that I read. I need to create a 3-dimentional array of `int` that will be able to store 30 values.

It's described as cuboid containing cubes. Each cube is supposed to be a cell and they should store ints from `30` to `59`. How should it look like? I try to draw it but it's pretty hard for me. Here is what I've tried.

```
public class cw124{

    public static void main (String[]args){
        int tab[][][]=new int[31][30][30];
        int wypelniacz=30;

        for (int i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<tab[j].length; j++){
                wypelniacz=30;

                for (int k=0; k<tab[k].length; k++){
                    tab[i][j][k]=wypelniacz++;                      
                }               
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<tab[j].length; j++){    
                for (int k=0; k<tab[k].length; k++){
                    wypelniacz=30;
                    tab[i][j][k]=wypelniacz++;
                    System.out.println("Row "+i+" Cell 1 "+j+" Cell 2 "+k+" "+tab[i][j][k]);
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the assignment, perhaps you could quote the full assignment in the question? One observation: *"I need to create 3dimentional array of int that will be able to store 30 values."* Your `tab` array stores 27,900 values (31 x 30 x 30). A three-dimensional array where all the dimensions are the same can't store 30 values; you can get close with a 3 x 3 x 3 array (27 values). Of course, an three-dimensional array where the dimensions aren't all the same can (3 x 2 x 5, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Your 3D array currently has 31*30*30 = 27,900 cells. If you need a 3D array with 30 cells, you can do this:

```java
int tab[][][]=new int[5][3][2];
```

This will give you a 3D array with 5*3*2 = 30 cells.
You can imagine each value in square brackets to be the length of one side of the cuboid.

The next step would be:

```java
int counter = 30;
for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < tab[0].length; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < tab[0][0].length; k++)
        {
             tab[i][j][k] = counter;
             counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will populate all the cells with numbers from 30 to 59.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, I think. (You can tell I think that from the fact I made the same point in a comment. :-) Amusingly, we even picked the same example dimensions, though in a different order, for the 30-value 3D array.)

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the entire comment. Added next step as well.

Comment: @GameDroids, the `++` in `counter++` is a post-increment, the increment takes place *after* the assignment (as opposed to `++counter` which is a pre-increment). Moving the increment to the next line is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code may help you understand the task.

You have to think of the 3 dimensions as a cube, the cube contains grids, each grid has rows which then have multiple columns)

(imagine a Rubik's cube, which has 3 layers=grids, each grid then has 3 rows and each of those rows again has 3 columns)

```
final int gridCount = 5;
final int rowCount = 5;
final int colsPerRow = 15;
final int[][][] cube = new int[gridCount][rowCount][colsPerRow];

for (final int[][] grid : cube) {
  for (int col = 0; col  < grid.length; col++) { //just to show the two different versions of 'for'
    final int[] row = grid[col];
    row[col] = 42+ col; //set it to whatever number
  }
}
```